# Block foul language feature?

Tags: feature-request, languages, censor

I just saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403296/sizin-ben-ananizi-sikim) (now deleted) that had a lot of [offensive language in it](http://translate.google.nl/#tr/en/Beyler%20ald%C4%B1rmay%C4%B1n%20fena%20s%C4%B1k%C4%B1l%C4%B1yorum%20%C5%9Fuan%20hepinize%20yard%C4%B1rcam.%0A%0ASizin%20ben%20topunuzun%20anas%C4%B1n%C4%B1%20sikim.%20Orospu%20evlatlar%C4%B1%20pi%C3%A7in%20d%C3%B6lleri.%20Bac%C4%B1n%C4%B1z%C4%B1%201%20dolara%20sikeyim%20amc%C4%B1k%20a%C4%9F%C4%B1zl%C4%B1%20g%C3%B6t%20veren%20dinazor%20da%C5%9F%C5%9Faklar%C4%B1.%20Varm%C4%B1%20lan%20i%C3%A7inizde%20ibne%20olan%20ona%20%C3%B6zel%20yard%C4%B1ray%C4%B1m%20am%C4%B1na%20kodu%C4%9Fumun%20gavatlar%C4%B1.%20Anan%C4%B1z%C4%B1n%20am%C4%B1na%20zurna%20sokupda%20Bethoven%20%C3%B6tt%C3%BCrim%20emi%20orospu%20%C3%A7ocuklar%C4%B1.%0A%0AEdit:%20Eksileyenin%20anas%C4%B1n%C4%B1%20sikerim.%20Konuyu%20sikeninde%20anas%C4%B1n%C4%B1%20sikerim) (Google translation; it was written in Turkish).

I flagged the question, and commented. After others commented, the OP continued to use offensive language in Turkish in the [comments](http://translate.google.nl/#tr/en/@%20Sotirios%20Delimanolis%20anan%C4%B1%20siktirmeyi%20%C3%A7ok%20mu%20istiyorsun%20pi%C3%A7) (Google translation). The post was then deleted, for posting in an non-English language, or cursing, I don't know.

But, is it a possibility that Stack Overflow can add a feature that blocks the usage of foul language?

Comment: The logs for Google Translate must be hilarious sometimes...

Comment: You mean block it in any language, including Alienish? Doesn't sound possible to me. Such posts are dealt with quickly, nothing to worry about. :)

Comment: Yet another reason not to use Google Translate for posts on SO.

Comment: 011001100111010101100011011010110010000001110100011010000110100101110011

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd oh, Binarish!

Comment: Yes, even klingon. I didn't know that `"inappropriate language" will be deleted with a single offensive flag (by a non-moderator), rather than requiring several.` so i thaught i asked.

Comment: 0100011001101100011000010110011101100111011001010110010000100000011000010111001100100000011011110110011001100110011001010110111001110011011010010111011001100101 @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd egaugnal taht nrael ot deen I !nmaD

Comment: @Bart At least you took the time to read :)

Comment: @Bart: Is this your attempt at cussing-out Community User?  If so, I applaud you.

Answer (score 9):

It is already the case that content that has "inappropriate language" will be deleted with a single offensive flag (by a non-moderator), rather than requiring several.

This makes it easy to remove inappropriate content when posted, but prevents cases of false positives (for example, discussions *about* inappropriate language on meta) where the inappropriate word is used in an appropriate context from deleting appropriate content.

It simply seems to be the case that Turkish swear words aren't on the blacklist.

Comment: I don't think "accept" or "accepted" is inappropriate language. There's just a list of words that if one found in the comment, it will be removed by one single flag.